# Unity InvalidOperationException: StandardIn has not been redirected

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am getting the following exception in my unity project as soon as the editor opens.

```
InvalidOperationException: StandardIn has not been redirected.
System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardInput () (at <3845a180c26b4889bc2d47593a665814>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardInput()
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.RunViaShell (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVars, GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler, System.Boolean useShellExecution, System.Boolean stdoutRedirectionInShellMode) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLine.cs:604)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.Run (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] envVars, GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLine.cs:510)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine+<RunAsync>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLine.cs:134)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
UnityEngine.UnhandledExceptionHandler:<RegisterUECatcher>m__0(Object, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
```

This exception first started to occur after a series of events. The original goal that I was trying to achieve was enabling push notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). After I installed the FirebaseMessaging unity package I could not resolve cretin jar files for my Android build. After doing some research I found a unity GitHub page that led me to installing play-services-resolver-1.2.121.0 unity package. That fixed the resolving of the jars, but then I was getting a dex issue on build. Long story short I ended up backing out all of my changes and I started to get the above exception.

I have tried getting a new version of my project from Unity Cloud Code, that didn't help. I upgraded to Unity 2018.4.X from 2018.3.X also didn't help. Resolving and force resolving Android dependencies didn't do anything either.

I cannot build or run my game in the Unity editor. On start up unity tries to resolve Android dependencies but never makes any progress. A console window pops up but doesn't seem to do anything. I have put over 2000 hours into my game in the last year and I would hate to lose it now. If anyone has any clues to what might help I would be grateful.

Thank you,
Travis

Comment: it would be near on impossible to help, we would need a [mcve] on how to reproduce this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. After digging some more on the internet I was led to a page completely in Russian, after I used google translate someone suggested remove all punctuation from the unity folder name. Low and behold this was the solution. I had an apostrophe in the names of one of the folders. After it was removed the project worked again.